# Onclick of button, the content and color property has to exchange the positions

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am creating some puzzle and there are 4 button on it wen i clicks on any one of them it the target box should replace that box which is given by the box number for example: if i click on button 4 , then target should replace the box and take position

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp65m3uw/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btn').off('click').on('click', function() {

    $(".target1").attr('class', 'target');


  });

});
```

```css
.main_box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 16px 16px 134px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.big_box {
  width: 488px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(162, 255, 224, 0.67);
  margin: 8px 11px 13px 58px;
  border: 1px solid #c51ae2;
  border-radius: 53px;
}

.target {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 205px;
  top: 127px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.target1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ea5cd8;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16px;
  top: 16px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.target2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #59a8e6;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 388px;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.target3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #FFC107;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 240px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.target4 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #607D8B;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 393px;
  top: 238px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 402px 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#hello_1 {
  left: 67px;
}

#hello_2 {
  left: 173px;
}

#hello_3 {
  left: 290px;
}

#hello_4 {
  left: 410px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_box">
  <div class="big_box">
    <div class="target">Tar</div>
    <div class="target1">1</div>
    <div class="target2">2</div>
    <div class="target3">4</div>
    <div class="target4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_1">btn 1</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_2">btn 2</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_3">btn 3</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_4">btn 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the question is ?

Comment: so when you click on button4, the div with class `.target4` must go and replace the `green` div with class `.target` , and what should go instead of `target4` ( the yellow div ) . If that div goes instead of green box

Comment: actually for example: when i click on button 4 that time 'Tar' box should take the position of 'box 4' with content  and 'box 4' should be removed,(similarly for all the boxes)

Comment: Your question makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#hello_1').off('click').on('click', function() {

    /*$(".target1").attr('class', 'target').css({background:'#ea5cd8'});*/
    $(".target").css({top: 16, left: 16, zIndex:999});
   
  });
    $('#hello_2').off('click').on('click', function() {
 /*   $(".target2").attr('class', 'target').css({background:'#59a8e6'});*/
 $(".target").css({top: 15, left: 388, zIndex:999});

  });
  $('#hello_3').off('click').on('click', function() {
  /*  $(".target3").attr('class', 'target').css({background:'#FFC107'});*/
  $(".target").css({top: 240, left: 20, zIndex:999});

  });

  $('#hello_4').off('click').on('click', function() {
   /* $(".target4").attr('class', 'target').css({background:'#607D8B'});*/
    $(".target").css({top: 238, left: 393, zIndex:999});

  });

});
```

```css
.main_box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 16px 16px 134px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.big_box {
    width: 488px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(162, 255, 224, 0.67);
    margin: 8px 11px 13px 58px;
    border: 1px solid #c51ae2;
    border-radius: 53px;
}

.target {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 205px;
    top: 127px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.target1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ea5cd8;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 16px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.target2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #59a8e6;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 388px;
    top: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.target3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #FFC107;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
    top: 240px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.target4 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #607D8B;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 393px;
    top: 238px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 402px 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
#hello_1 {
    left: 67px;
}
#hello_2 {
    left: 173px;
}
#hello_3 {
    left: 290px;
}
#hello_4 {
    left: 410px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
 Puzzle box  
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ind.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ind.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div class="main_box">
  <div class="big_box">
   <div class="target">Tar</div>
   <div class="target1">1</div>
   <div class="target2">2</div>
   <div class="target3">3</div>
   <div class="target4">4</div>
  
  </div>

  <div class="btn" id="hello_1">btn 1</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_2">btn 2</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_3">btn 3</div>
  <div class="btn" id="hello_4">btn 4</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

so, this is what i wanted its done i hope you all understood thanks for the help
here its https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/17554/